# Ошибка только на стенде org.codehaus.stax2.XMLStreamWriter2.writeInt(I)V

Tags: java, xml, xmlparser, javax

С чем связана такая ошибка?
Локально работает нормально.
На стенде jboss падает ошибка

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.stax2.XMLStreamWriter2.writeInt(I)V</u></p><p><b>JBWEB000069: description</b> <u>JBWEB000145: The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.</u></p><p><b>JBWEB000070: exception</b> <pre>org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.stax2.XMLStreamWriter2.writeInt(I)V
```

Ошибка случается в методе парсинга xml строки в java объект

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/putNewMessages", method = RequestMethod.PUT,
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE,
            produces = "application/xml")
    public ResponseEntity<ValifInfo> putSpSaveDataToNewStructure(@RequestBody String request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        Messages messages = null;

        try {
            JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Messages.class);
            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
            messages = (Messages) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(request));
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
```

зависимости

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
            <version>8.1.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
                    <artifactId>wstx-asl</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Welcome to JAR HELL ) Ищите, кто тащит, в качестве транзитивных зависимостей, разные версии одной и той же библиотеки.

Comment: точно!! есть клятая com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat которая тащит org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:3.1.1. я прочел что можно как то через exclusion запретить